# Не создается сетевой адаптер private_network Vagrant Centos 7

Tags: centos, сеть, vagrant

В Vagrantfile прописываю private network:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.4.4.30"
```

Но при запуске не создается сетевое подключение с данным ip.
Если же в гостевой машине перезагрузить сеть, то он появляется.
В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо.

Comment: Помогло отключение службы NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло отключение службы NetworkManager.